# Global.asax template not available in Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2012, global-asax, missing-features

When I attempt to "add new item" to my web project (by right-clicking, add new item) - there is no template for it.  What might the problem be?  I'm using VS2008.

Additional Info:
When I right click on the solution and "Add", "New Web Site" - I have zero tempates to choose from.
I have tried running `devenv /installvstemplates` and this template box is still empty.

I have only three templates in the following directory.
 Is there somewhere I can just copy the other templates from manually?

> C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   9.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\Web\CSharp\1033

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the answer for me was re-installing VS.  Not exactly sure what the issue was, but that fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

Try opening the Visual Studio command prompt (as an administrator) and run `devenv.exe /Setup` from your VS 2008 installation path (C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE in my case), or run from the same prompt: `devenv /installvstemplates`

Answer (score 1):

**Update:**

It looks like multiple people reported [the same problem](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vssetup/thread/9f763b7c-4ca7-4c45-98ac-97ef50a6b473).

There's [a hot fix](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Downloads/DownloadDetails.aspx?DownloadID=10826) available that might help you.

Comment: Thanks - but still no go.  It looks like the templates are not installed in my program files directory.

Answer (score 1):

It is probably your project type. Try creating a new project of type web.

Comment: I think this is on the right track, but when I right click on the solution and "Add", "New Web Site" - I have zero tempates to choose from.

Comment: Sounds like there is something wrong with your VS installation. You should try re installing.