# Global.asax template not available in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2008, global-asax

Actually I want to add a Global.asax file in my web project.
When I attempt to "add new item" to my web project (by right-clicking, add new item) Global Application class file template is not available.

When i checked the following path in my system

> C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio9.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\Web\CSharp\1033

GlobalAsax zipped files are available.

How to add this templates to my visual studio 2008 template list or how to add Gobal.asax file to my visual studio 2008...Pls help me.

i ref the question-[Global.asax template not available in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1500688/global-asax-template-not-available-in-visual-studio)

Comment: are you creating ne web Application or web site? in web site no cs file will be added

Comment: @Dinav i was adding global application class file to vs2008..  ref:http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2011/05/how-to-add-globalasaxcs-file-in-aspnet.html                                                                             but in installed templates it was not there.